# How to add child relationships when creating a new object in the Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity framework project setup.  It it I have four tables and three entities ("A", "B", & "C").  There is a 1:n relationship between A and B, and between A and C, and a n:n relationship between B and C.

[image]

I use the following code to try to add a new "B" entity:

```
A t = null;
if (this.MyA == null)
{
    t = new A()
    {
        EntityKey = this.MyAReference.EntityKey,
        AId = (Guid)this.MyAReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value
    };
}
else
{
    t = this.MyA;
}
this.MyA = null;
context.Attach(t);
this.MyA = t;
```

The "B" object ("this") has a child collection of "C" objects.  These "C" objects already exist in the database, but are not related to the new object (obviously).  When I call "SaveChanges()", it throws an exception because it tries to add all of the child "C" objects an new objects in the database.

How can I get it to just create the reference in the "Table_JoinBC", and not try to recreate the "C" objects?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier if you use [stub entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx)

You stated that you wanted to add a new B object.  And to add a B object you need an A object

Here is an example using stub entities:

```
A myAObject = new A { A_Id = 5 };

Context.AttachTo("Aes", myAObject);

B myBObject = new B { B_ID = 6, A = myAObject);

Context.AddToBes(myBObject)
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: A useful tip, but it does not appear to solve the problem.  I have tried several different configurations with no luck.

Comment: @Sako73... I just updated my answer with an example on how to add a new B object using STUB Entities

Comment: What would be shortest and cleanest solution to do the same thing if you are not sure if A is in database and in some cases it also should be inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got to work, with the child collections:

```
A myAObject = new A { A_Id = 5 };

Context.AttachTo("Aes", myAObject);

B myBObject = new B () { 
    B_ID = 6, 
    A = myAObject};

foreach( C c_obj in CsCollection){
    Context.AttachTo("Cs", c_obj);
    myBObject.C.Add(c_obj);
}


Context.AddToProducts(myBObject)
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks.